# Custom Filter Attribute does not run on code call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, filterattribute, asp.net-mvc-custom-filter

I am using a Custom Action Filter to authorize users to Actions, some of which return an ActionResult while others return a JsonResult.

For every regular action system performs OK. But, now I have another requirement to implement where my design fails.

The View posts to:

```
[AuthorizationFilter(Entity = AuthEntity.MyItem, Permission = AuthPermission.Write)]
public JsonResult Edit(MyModel model)
```

where I check the user's authorization for **Write** operation. This check performs OK. But actually my Action just checks a condition and the redirects the Action to another Action in the Controller as follows:

```
[AuthorizationFilter(Entity = AuthEntity.MyItem, Permission = AuthPermission.Write)]
public JsonResult Edit(MyModel model)
{
    if (model.Id == 0)
    {
        return Insert(model);
    }
    else
    {
        return Update(model);
    }
}
```

Also the Update Action checks for a certain state which requires another authorization:

```
public JsonResult Update(MyModel model)
{
    if (model.StatusId == (int)Shared.Enumerations.Status.Approved)
        {
            return UpdateRequiresApproval(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return UpdateRequiresNonApproval(model);
        }
    }

[AuthorizationFilter(Entity = AuthEntity.MyItem, Permission = AuthPermission.Approve)]
public JsonResult UpdateRequiresApproval(MyModel model)
```

The thing is, although I have a custom attribute filter defined on **UpdateRequiresApproval** action it does not run the filter (possibly) because it is being redirected by another action by means of a code call, but not from the View directly.

How can I make my filter run when code falls to the **UpdateRequiresApproval** action?

Regards.

Comment: return **RedirectToActio**n will work fibe

Comment: Nope. return RedirectToAction("Update", "MyController"); says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'"

Comment: Maybe you can make a separate function and call it from `UpdateRequiresApproval` and from `Update`, this way you won't be dependent on the attributes/signature of `UpdateRequiresApproval`.

Comment: I don't think that I understood your solution but Custom Action Filters don't seem to run unless you call them directly from the View itself. And directly calling it from my View will expose my logic to the end-user which is not a good thing, because the user might just make a Jax call to Update instead of UpdateRequiresApproval and surpass the authorization.